# Feasibility of making a quantum destabilizer

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons, quantum

In an advanced dystopian future, humanity has made a weapon that is capable of destabilizing quantum particles. This has resulted in the mass death of civilians and has caused massive destruction to the surrounding area.

When the weapon is shot, it is said to have an effect on frequencies, causing some functioning electronics to turn off and not turn back on for x amount of time.

Could such a weapon feasibly exist, and if not, why?

Comment: I will say, that I don’t know much on quantum physics, on what  properties they show, and what they have an effect on

Comment: Do you mean antimatter?

Comment: The humans in this future dystopian society aren’t advanced enough to use antimatter

Comment: To be honest, as it stands, this sounds like [technobabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technobabble). What do you mean by a "quantum destabilizer"?

Comment: A quantum destabilized is exactly what it sounds likes, it’s a machine or weapon (in this case a weapon) that is designed to disrupt ad destabilize quantum particles or fields

Comment: @RotNDecay Right, but what does "destabilize" mean? Does it destroy them? I'm also not sure what you mean by "quantum particle" - do you mean a particle like a proton or an electron?

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily destroy the particles, it merely causes unrest or upsets the stability or the particles. And quantum particles are, from my understanding, leptons, quarks, and bosons

Comment: Ah, so you're saying it causes particles to decay into other particles?

Comment: If I my basic understanding of quantum physics is correct then yes

Comment: You know what upsets the frequencies of particles? A gun. You really must be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a hard-science perspective, the answer is obviously unknown because such a weapon would rely on scientific and engineering principles that remain undiscovered...

But;

I think that it is feasible considering a couple of ideas that we have around physics at the moment. The first is far from mainstream, but the second is a well understood principle that, if coupled with the first, could result in the effects you describe.

The first idea that could lead to this effect is known as the [Holographic Paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_brain_theory), which has applications both in neurophysiology and in quantum physics. Put simply, the idea is that the universe is encoded within every part of the universe and that therefore tearing a chunk out of the fabric of the universe would not actually rip away a *part* of the universe; it would remain whole just with less *detail*. In neurophysiology, the same is thought to be true of the human brain and the human mind - taking away part of the human brain is thought not to take away a chunk of memory or skill, just lower the detail available across the whole.

I won't go into too much detail on this other than to say that for this to be true, the human brain AND the universe both have to be based more on wave theory than particle (or *quantum*) theory insofar as it is the wave that stores the information, not the location at which the wave is observed. (Massive simplification but functionally correct for the purposes of this question.)

The point being, that in such a case a weapon that destabilises the fabric of the universe at the quantum level may well do so via wave disruption.

If that is the case, then the second element comes into play, namely the [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance). The idea here is that if you are disrupting quantum 'waves' by creating an interference wave, then resonance could arguably impact higher level wave functions, potentially disrupting electronic equipment if it operates on a frequency of harmonic resonance.

Let's say (for instance) that your disruptor operates at a very small frequency (which it would likely do so given you're trying to disrupt quantum cohesion), then multiples of that frequency would be manifold and as such, most electronic equipment nearby probably would end up on the fritz for at least a while until the effect dies down. Arguably, the closer you are to the epicentre of the blast combined with how sensitive your equipment is would determine how long the effect lasts - if normal physics apply then the force of the wave would dissipate by the cube of the distance from the epicentre, and I would assume that the effect to be useful would take some finite time to dissipate rather than be instantly 'off' once you turn off the weapon. But, these are assumptions.

In any event, if you find a way to turn the holographic paradigm into a solid theory, then use that theory to create a destabiliser, you may well have a device that coincidentally generates an EMP effect that can disrupt electronic fields. As to how likely that is, well I'll leave it to your own reading on the holographic paradigm to determine, and your own writing skill to make the weapon believable regardless.